# :after pseudoelement overlapping with link after browser resize

Tags: html, css

I've recently discovered a problem with the formatting of my site's footer and couldn't figure out how to solve it.

I have a series of links with a "\" :after pseudoelement serving as a divider between each link. When the link text is more than 40 characters and the browser is narrowed, the link text splits and wraps to the next line, but the divider remains on the line and overlaps with the first part of the link text. How do I change the CSS so that the divider also wraps around and is displayed at the end of each link even when the link text is long or wraps to the next line?

Answer (score 1):

I had to convert your less to Css put nevertheless you just need to  change position property of ul.links li a:after to relative

```css
ul.links {
  margin: 25px 0 0 0;
}
ul.links li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.links li:last-child a:after {
  display: none;
}
ul.links li a {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
ul.links li a:after {
  content: "|";
  position: relative;
  right: -10px;
  top: -4px;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="links">
        <li><a href="foo">bar1</a></li>
        <li><a href="foo">bar2</a></li>
        <li><a href="foo">bar3</a></li>
        <li><a href="foo">bar4</a></li>
        <li><a href="foo">bar5</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the attribute of after to:(top=>bottom)

```
&:after {
      content: "|";
      position: absolute;
      right: -10px;
      bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reach something similar with border... removing :after

```
a {
   position: relative;
   margin-right: 10px;
   border-right: 1px solid #000;
   padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This works. However, I'd like to figure out how to do this with other divider characters such as "\", so I edited the question to reflect this.